# Using CSS to place element over another

Tags: html, css

I need to place an `<input>` exactly over an `<a>`, have the edges of the `<input>` link up with the outer boarder of the `<a>`, and not change any other presentation.  Please see https://jsbin.com/cotogimaqo (script duplicated below).

The following information is known about `a.link` and can (but not must) be used in the CSS.

```
width   39px
height  17px
outerWidth w/o margin   99px
outerWidth w/ margin    159px
outerHeight w/o margin  77px
outerHeight w/ margin   137px
```

In `Attempt 1`, I thought I could use `position:absolute` and pin the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` positions, however, it doesn't work.

In `Attempt 2`, `Attempt 3`, and `Attempt 4`, I tried several other things, but still it doesn't work.

`Attempt 5` is pretty accurate, but I have no idea why it is, and was accomplished by trial and error.

How can this be accomplished?  Please provide explanation on "why" it works, and not just a quick fix.

PS.  Note that I asked a similar question [How do I place one element precisely over another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33307083/how-do-i-place-one-element-precisely-over-another-element), however, did not get any answers, and that question was related to JavaScript.  This question is very different and only deals with CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Testing</title>  
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .box{margin:5px;padding:5px;border: 1px solid black;width:200px;}
            .link{margin:30px;padding:20px;border: 10px solid black;}
            .divWrapper{margin:0;padding:0;display:inline; position:relative;}
            #wrapper{width:600px;}
            #info{float:right;}
            .divWrapper input{margin:0;border: 1px dashed red;cursor:pointer;} /*.divWrapper input{z-index:9999;opacity:0;} */
            /* this is the part I need help with.
            Known information about a.link:
            width 38px, height 18px, outerWidth w/o margin 98px, outerWidth w/ margin 158px, outerHeight w/o margin 78px, outerHeight w/ margin 138px
            */
            #div1 input{
                position:absolute;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;
            }
            #div2 input{
                position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
                width:98px;height:78px;
            }
            #div3 input{
                position:absolute;top:0;left:0;
                width:98px;height:78px;
                margin:30px;
            }
            #div4 input{
                position:absolute;top:30px;left:30px;
                width:98px;height:78px;
            }
            #div5 input{
                position:absolute;top:-30px;left:30px;
                width:98px;height:78px;
            }

        </style> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /*The following JavaScript is just to provide link information and is not related to the question */
            $(function () {
                var link=$('#div1 a.link');
                var tableRows=$('#info tr');
                tableRows.eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text(link.css('width'));
                tableRows.eq(1).find('td').eq(1).text(link.css('height'));
                tableRows.eq(2).find('td').eq(1).text(link.outerWidth(false)+'px');
                tableRows.eq(3).find('td').eq(1).text(link.outerWidth(true)+'px');
                tableRows.eq(4).find('td').eq(1).text(link.outerHeight(false)+'px');
                tableRows.eq(5).find('td').eq(1).text(link.outerHeight(true)+'px');
                $('.divWrapper').click(function(){alert('input clicked.');return false;})
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="info">
                <h2>a.link info</h2>
                <table>
                    <tr><td>width</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>height</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>outerWidth w/o margin</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>outerWidth w/ margin</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>outerHeight w/o margin</td><td></td></tr>
                    <tr><td>outerHeight w/ margin</td><td></td></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div id="div1" class="box"><p>Attempt 1</p>Vel labitur sanctus antiopam at. <div class="divWrapper"><a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a><input type="file" name="bla"></div>.  Ludus temporibus et duo. Nullam consequuntur comprehensam id eos, nec ad quot mucius oportere.</div>
            <div id="div2" class="box"><p>Attempt 2</p>Vel labitur sanctus antiopam at. <div class="divWrapper"><a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a><input type="file" name="bla"></div>.  Ludus temporibus et duo. Nullam consequuntur comprehensam id eos, nec ad quot mucius oportere.</div>
            <div id="div3" class="box"><p>Attempt 3</p>Vel labitur sanctus antiopam at. <div class="divWrapper"><a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a><input type="file" name="bla"></div>.  Ludus temporibus et duo. Nullam consequuntur comprehensam id eos, nec ad quot mucius oportere.</div>
            <div id="div4" class="box"><p>Attempt 4</p>Vel labitur sanctus antiopam at. <div class="divWrapper"><a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a><input type="file" name="bla"></div>.  Ludus temporibus et duo. Nullam consequuntur comprehensam id eos, nec ad quot mucius oportere.</div>
            <div id="div5" class="box"><p>Attempt 5</p>Vel labitur sanctus antiopam at. <div class="divWrapper"><a class="link" href="javascript:void(0)">LINK</a><input type="file" name="bla"></div>.  Ludus temporibus et duo. Nullam consequuntur comprehensam id eos, nec ad quot mucius oportere.</div>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `div.divWrapper` is wrapped around `a.link`, and takes on the width of the child element, but only the height of the **inline** child element without the padding, margin, or border.

So, when one uses absolute positioning on the `<input>`, it needs to be raised by the padding and border amount.

As for horizontal positioning, `left 0` would place it at the outer left margin of `<a>`, but since it should be placed at the border edit, it needs to be moved right by the margin.

The final CSS should be:

```
#divWorking input{
  position:absolute;
  top:-30px;    /* padding (20px) plus border (10px) */
  left:30px;    /* same as margin (30px) */
  width:98px;   /* text in <a> width plus <a> padding and border width */
  height:78px;  /* text in <a> height plus <a> padding and border height */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change every div -> input to:

```
input {
    height: 41px;
    left: 13px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -12px;
    width: 58px;
}
```

Comment: Why will this work?  I will need to be able to reproduce it with different size elements.  Thanks